# How do i read multiple json objects in django using POST method

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I am sending  multiple json object to server and django views how to get this multiple json objects and extracting each key value.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href='/static/js/file.txt' type="text/css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('static/js/file.txt', function (data) {
        var lines = data.split("\n");
        var dict = {};

        $.each(lines, function (n, elem) {
            var fields = elem.split("\t");
            var service_id = fields[0];
            dict[fields[0]] = {'owner':fields[1],'email':fields[2],'phone':fields[3],
            'model':fields[4],'date':fields[5],'problem':fields[6]};

        });
        var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(dict);
        //console.log(dict);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'load/data/',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {simple:jsonObj,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val()},
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (json) {
                $("#simple").append("<p>" + json + "</p>");

            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
</head>
<div id ="simple"></div>
</html>
```